# Utilização do "return" no module.exports

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em NodeJS e no momento, estou enfrentando alguns problemas ao retornar algum valor de uma função dentro de um módulo.

**Código:**

**Arquivo para queries**

```
async function query(query){
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const response = {
                status: true,
                data: result
            };
            return response;
        });
    });
}

// Teoricamente, era para a função query() retornar um JSON ao chamá-la

module.exports = query;
```

**Arquivo controller**

```
const conn = require('../sealed/con');
module.exports = {
    async index(request, response){
        const splans = await(conn(`SELECT * FROM table`));
        console.log(splans);
    }
};
```

Ao chamar a função dentro do meu controller, é retornado apenas `undefined`, mas se eu der um `console.log` na função `query`, funciona normalmente, o problema é que eu preciso desses valores retornados no meu controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tua função `query` não é assíncrona de maneira moderna, mas sim via *callback*. Assim tens de encapsular a função numa Promise e chamar o `resolve` da Promise quando as callbacks forem chamadas.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
async function query(query) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        const response = {
          status: true,
          data: result
        };
        res(response);
      });
    });
  });
}
```